# Python Dictionaries - Error Reading Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm messing with dictionaries, which I've never had a problem before. I've written a few loops to help match and clean out dict, except I keep getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Service02/Desktop/D/TT/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    if resultDict[currentImageTest] == oldDict["image" + str(j)]:
KeyError: 'image1'
```

No idea why there's a key error when it's obviously there. Confused. Any help is appreciated!

```
resultDict = {"image1":1, "image2":2, "image3":3, "image4":4, "image5": 5}
oldDict = {"image1":1, "image2":22, "image3":3, "image4":47, "image5": 5}

i=1
j=1
while i<6:
    currentImageTest = "image" + str(i)

    while j<6:
        if resultDict[currentImageTest] == oldDict["image" + str(j)]:
            del resultDict[currentImageTest]

        else:
            pass

        j+=1
    i+=1


print resultDict
```

**END RESULT (SOLVED):**

```
i=1
while i<6:
    currentImageTest = "image" + str(i)
    j=1
    while j<6:
        if oldDict["image" + str(j)] == resultDict[currentImageTest]:
            del resultDict[currentImageTest]
            break
        else:
            pass

        j+=1
    i+=1


print resultDict
```

Comment: you are trying to delete that resultDict entry on each iteration of i.  after the first its already gone so trying to access it is going to throw that error what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: incidentally, the usual way to write this kind of loop is  `for i in range(1, 6):`  That way you don't need to set `i=1` before the loop or write `i+=1` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if resultDict[currentImageTest] == oldDict["image" + str(j)]:
            del resultDict[currentImageTest]
```

here in first loop(`i=1` and `j=1`) you deleted `resultDict["image1"]` and the next loop (`i=1` and `j=2`) you're trying to compare `resultDict["image1"]`  with `oldDict["image2"]` , but as `resultDict["image1"]` is already deleted so no `key` is found

Edit:

better use `for` loop and `range()` instead of while here:

```
resultDict = {"image1":1, "image2":2, "image3":3, "image4":4, "image5": 5}
oldDict = {"image1":1, "image2":22, "image3":3, "image4":47, "image5": 5}

for i in range(1,6):
    currentImageTest = "image" + str(i)
    for j in range(1,6):
        if resultDict[currentImageTest] == oldDict["image" + str(j)]:
            del resultDict[currentImageTest]
            break
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Of course.. Forgot to add a break after the del command. Now I feel really stupid. Thank you though!

Comment: @Dboy1612 better use `for` loop and `range()` here instead of `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are trying to reference a key that does not exist, in this case, "image1". You want to use a check to make sure you don't run into a KeyError.

```
if resultDict.has_key(currentImageTest) and resultDict[currentImageTest] == oldDict["image" + str(j)]
```

either that or you can wrap it in a try..except